# There is a betterway to handle with the HttpServletResponse in the servlet using command pattern

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httpresponse

First of all, I'm using command pattern with this interface:

```
public CommandResponse execute(HttpServletRequest req)
            throws CommandException;
```

And this is my service method:

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Command cmd = lookupCommand(req.getParameter("cmd"));
            CommandResponse next = cmd.execute(req, res);
            CommandToken.set(req);

            if (next != null) {
                if (!req.getHeader("X-Requested-With").equals("XMLHttpRequest")) {
                    if (next.isRedirect()) {
                        redirect(next, res);
                    } else if (next.isForward()) {
                        forward(next, req, res);
                    }
                } else {
                    ajaxCall(next, res);
                }
            }
        } catch (CommandException e) {
            res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

As you can see my service method treats the logic of redirection and forward and my interface does not have access to the HttpServletResponse object. But for some actions of my servlet I need handle the response to add some content like a xml or a cookie. The more obvious way to achieve that is modify my interface to:

```
public CommandResponse execute(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                throws CommandException;
```

Now the questions:

1-) In my opinion the solution above will break the elengacy and safety of the code since my actions now have access to the response and can redirect and forward, and even add content to the response and let the service method use sendRedirect wich we know would have no effect. Am I right? To solve that I do this:

```
public class CommandResponse {

    private boolean redirect;
    private boolean forward;
    private String page;
    private String contentType;
    private String outContent;
    private HashMap headers;
    private List<Cookie> cookies;
    ...
    public void mapToResponse(HttpServletResponse res) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That is, I create a faked response and when I come back of the action execute method I map this faked response to the real http response (just if I have a forward or a ajax call).

2-) That is good? It makes sense? Should I not use it?

3-) There is a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd say that using a framework like JAX-RS or Spring MVC is nearly always better than hand-writing servlet logic.

Comment: Yes, but is a college project and I can't use one. Actually, I want learn more about possible patterns wich I can use,

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass a strong buffer to capture any content that your subsequent chain may want to add? This way you are not confusing the responsibility of the components. Normally, httpresponse is expected to behave as any one would expect.

However, I would like to hear the reason behind this design.

Comment: It is a college project and soon someone else should take my place in the development. I want to ensure that this person can use the structure that I created easily and it does not mess things up. Can you clarify: "Normally, httpresponse is expected to behave as any one would expect"

Comment: The normal behavior is , when component (down below in your chain) invokes http response.send redirect, a redirect should happen. Since you do not intend to support that, I don't see any reason to keep that method in interface. Create an interface that will have the methods that u will support.

Comment: So do you think that makes sense to replace from the service method the logic of "redirect" and "forward" and leave the "action" handle with it? Actually, I try to expand an implementation of servlet that I see in a book by Duane K. Fields, Mark A. Kolb, Shawn Bayern

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way, take a look to Frontman, an elegant implementation of the Command pattern in servlets
http://www.bibeault.org/frontman/